# Cast and pass protocol as method argument

Tags: ios, objective-c

Making a game where creatures can reproduce with others. I've defined a protocol so that certain creatures can breed.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to cast and pass the creature properly

```
// Creature may breed with any other creature allowed to breed
@protocol Mateable
-(void)mateWith:(id<Mateable> *)entity;
@end
```

When the player touches a creature, I have logic to cast the creature and pass it:

```
// If user taps on a create that can breed, we make it happen...
if( [touching conformsToProtocol:@protocol(Mateable)] ){
    id<Mateable> mate = (id<Mateable>) touching;
    [player mateWith:mate];
}
```

However, I'm getting an error:

`Cannot initialize the parameter of type '__autorelease <id>Mateable' with an lvalue of type '__strong id<Mateable>'`

How can I properly cast and pass the creature as the argument?

Answer (score 5):

you don't need `*` after `id` because `id` is already pointer type

so

```
// Creature may breed with any other creature allowed to breed
@protocol Mateable
-(void)mateWith:(id<Mateable>)entity;
@end
```

you should be able to figure it out yourself because your `mate` is `id<Mateable>` and you passing it to `id<Mateable> *`

Comment: That seems to have fixed it, thanks! I have to wait 10 minutes to accept this.